# Excel horizontal to vertical arrangement one after the other

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("A19:C19").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("B2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A20:C20").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet5").Select
Range("B6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

so basically i've data in horizontal, that when transposed together it comes in vertical but rows

I want one after the other
As in

```
A19 - Hyperlink
B19 - String
C19 - String
Space
A20 - HyperLink
B20 - String
C20 - String
```

And so on..

For example ...

[image]

would like this data, to look like this

[image]

Comment: And where are the examples of your data and the output your code is creating?  Why are you showing output in `C2`?

Comment: Fixed that, that was a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial with `Power Query`:

- Add Custom Column with Formula:  `= " "`  (a space)
- Select all the columns and "UnPivot"
- Delete the Attribute Column
- In the Value column, Replace **space** with **null**

If you add/change rows (or columns), merely refresh the query.

#### M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each " "),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Added Custom", {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Columns"," ",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value1",{"Attribute"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

**If you do not have access to Power Query**, and from your comment it seems there may be a company imposed policy about downloading add-ins, even if they are from Microsoft, then you can use VBA.

Be sure to read the comments in the code to help understand what it is doing.

I suggest early-binding, as written, as you get the benefits of intellisense and a more efficient execution.  But if you are going to distribute the code, late-binding might be better.

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  (or you could use late binding)
Option Explicit
Sub organizeData()
    Dim D As Dictionary, COL As Collection
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim C As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, V As Variant, W As Variant
    
'Set source and results worksheets and ranges
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7") 'or whatever

    'Assuming first cell is the first cell starting with "http"
    ' but could make other assumptions, or even hard code.
    'Also assuming the source data range is contiguous.
    With wsSrc
        Set C = .Cells.Find(what:="http*", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, _
                            searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                            
        If C Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No cell starting with http"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        'Read into variant array for speed of processing
        vSrc = C.CurrentRegion
    End With
    
    'for purposes of convenience, will put results onto same worksheet,
    'below the source data, but could write it to another area or sheet,
    'or even overwrite the original data, but I would not advise this latter.
    Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet7")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(10, 2)
    
'Read the data into a dictionary, with each dictionary representing one line of data
Set D = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'if there is a header row, then start with 2
    Set COL = New Collection
    For J = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    
    'decide how you want to handle empty data
    'I will NOT include a blank row, (except between groups), but you can change that behavior here
        If Not Trim(vSrc(I, J)) = "" Then COL.Add vSrc(I, J)
    Next J
        D.Add Key:=I, Item:=COL
Next I

'Create results array
'If leaving blanks for empty rows, don't need this computation,
'  but it won't hurt to leave it in.

'Get number of rows
I = D.Count 'for the blank rows
For Each V In D
    I = I + D(V).Count 'for each eventual rows
Next V

'if going to write a header row, start then use ...(0 to 1, 1 to 1)
'   and write the header into vRes(0,1)
ReDim vRes(1 To I, 1 To 1)

'Get the data and populate the array
I = 0
For Each V In D
    For J = 1 To D(V).Count
        I = I + 1
        vRes(I, 1) = D(V)(J)
    Next J
    I = I + 1
Next V
        
'write results to worksheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) - 1) 'else last row would be blank
With rRes
    Range(rRes, Cells(wsRes.Rows.Count, .Column)).Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Style = "Output"
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]mgur.com/fvd5K.png

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't have access to Power query and i tried downloading it at the workdesk, but it  isn't allowing me to do so, 
Is there any other way?

Comment: @KaviHarjani What version of Excel? Windows or MAC?

Comment: Excel version 2010 on windows 7

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank-you sir! 
You are awesome!!

Comment: Helpful and extensive answer+) - Hint to internationalization: the `Style` property follows regional naming conventions; e.g. in German `.Style="Output"` would be `.Style="Ausgabe"`. This can be avoided using `rRes.Style = ThisWorkbook.Styles(25).Name` referencing the workbook's Styles collection. - FYI posted an alternative blockwise array approach.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Ron's approach this demonstrates two short and rather simple solutions to reorganize horizontal data to one vertical including space lines.

**a) blockwise array approach**

Just for fun a blockwise array solution; change the `ExampleCall()` procedure to your needs *(I abstained from defining source or target ranges to keep it short)*:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExampleCall()
With Sheet1                              ' << change to your sheet's VB Editor's Code(Name)
    ReOrg .Range("A2:C4"), .Range("C10") ' args: source range, target range, number of blank rows
End With
End Sub

Sub ReOrg(src As Range, target As Range, Optional ByVal nBlanks As Long = 1)
    Dim v: v = src                       ' assign src to a 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    Dim BlockLength As Long: BlockLength = UBound(v, 2) + nBlanks
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)               ' write original line data blockwise to target
        target.Offset((i - 1) * BlockLength).Resize(UBound(v, 2)) = Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, i, 0))
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**b) Getting 1 array sequence via simple cell loop - added/2020-04-09**

If you prefer to reorganize to a vertical column array (optionally to a "flat" one as well) via cell loop, you could try this:

```
Sub ExampleCall2()
    Dim arr
    arr = Rng2Arr(Sheet1.Range("A2:C4"), IsOneDim:=False) ' get vertical array (i.e. 2-dim)
    Sheet1.Range("C10").Resize(UBound(arr), 1) = arr      ' write original line data into any column
End Sub

Function Rng2Arr(ByVal rng As Range, Optional ByVal nBlanks As Long = 1, Optional IsOneDim As Boolean = True) As Variant()
'Purpose: return 1-based array; if IsOneDim then 1-dim "flat" array, otherwise 2-dim (1 column)
'Note:    assumes empty cells in added column(s); independant from Application.MoveAfterReturnDirection
    Set rng = rng.Resize(ColumnSize:=rng.Columns.Count + nBlanks)  ' provide for blank cell
    ReDim tmp(1 To rng.Cells.Count)                                ' temp array to hold cell values
    Dim c As Range, i As Long
    For Each c In rng: i = i + 1: tmp(i) = c: Next c               ' rowwise assignment to temp
    Rng2Arr = IIf(IsOneDim, tmp, Application.Transpose(tmp))       ' return type following your preferences
End Function
```